# insert character automatically while typing a date in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Say I have this html:

```
<input class="input-date" type="text" placeholder="DD.MM.YY" ng-model="hctrl.dateInput">
```

While the user is typing the date I want to automatically insert `.` at the proper places.

I tried solving this with `$watch` like this:

```
.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        var controller = this;
        controller.pageClass = 'page-home'
        controller.dateInput = '';

        $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function() {
            return this.dateInput;
        }), function(newVal, oldVal){

            var str = newVal.replace(/[.]/g, "");

            console.log('oldVal: ' + oldVal + ' newVal: ' + newVal + ' str: ' + str);

            if(str.length % 2 == 0 && str.length >= 2 && str.length <= 6) {
                console.log(str.length); 
                controller.dateInput += '.';
            }    
        });

    }])
```

But this causes an infinite loop due to me adding to `controller.dateInput` while being inside the `$watch`.

What would be a proper way to solve this?

Comment: Where do you want to insert "." ?

Comment: @pravee-n the format is `DD.MM.YY`

Comment: You need to create a directive for this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wawy suggested, you should use a directive. If you don't want to choose angular-ui which has a Mask directive, you can roll your own. Here is some code to get you started.

```
myApp.directive("dateFormat", function() {
            var directive = {};

            directive.restrict = 'A'; // only as attribute
            directive.require = 'ngModel'; // communicate with the parent HTML tags ngModelController
            directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch(function() { return ctrl.$modelValue }, function(newVal, oldVal){
                    console.log("value in my parent is: " + newVal);
                    // logic here, such as if (newVal.endsWith('.'))...
                });
            }
            return directive;
        });
```

And then in your HTML:
<input type="text" ng-model="my.model" date-format>

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using a model, why not use a parser for your custom validation? Using scope watch is unnecessary. You should write a directive that requires the ngmodel controller. Then you can push a parser function to that controller that will do what you want.

You can read more about parsers and formatters in the documentation, here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

**EDIT:** i was a bit wrong, setviewvalue is not even required. I would advise using parsers instead of scope watch though.

here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8unudnr/2/

```
app.directive('parserFormatterExample', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                // logic goes here
                var newValue = viewValue.replace(/[.]/g, "");
                return newValue;               
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/) install and use it and put the following syntax in your input:

```
<input class="input-date" type="text" placeholder="DD.MM.YY" ng-model="hctrl.dateInput" ui-mask="99.99.9999" model-view-value="true">
```

The model-view-value will keep the mask on your model object.